# Swipe to delete overlapping issue on custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am seeing a strange overlapping issue when I swipe to delete a custom UITableViewCell. When I tap on my cell, I show it in expanded mode and then user can swipe to delete that row. Please see below the attached screenshot of the overlapping.

Any clue what might have gone wrong here?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you took a photo. Take a screenshot instead so it is clear. I can't tell what your issue is from the fuzzy picture you posted.

Comment: @rmaddy: Actually I took a screenshot from the video as this happens when I tap on Delete button so does not get time to capture the screenshot while this transition in happening.